# Agregação e composição em diversos relacionamentos

Tags: java, design-pattern, uml

Dada uma classe A, digamos que a relação entre essa classe A e uma classe B seja de composição, onde A é a classe "todo" e B é a classe "parte". Dada uma terceira classe C, pode haver outra composição entre B e C, de forma que nesse novo relacionamento C seja o "todo" e B a "parte"? Segue um exemplo abaixo de como seria isso no diagrama de classes:

[image: Multiplas composições]

Outra dúvida: tendo uma classe B é possível que ela se relacione com uma classe A por meio de uma composição e com uma classe C por meio de uma agregação? Segue um exemplo abaixo de como seria isso no diagrama de classes:

[image: Composição/agregação]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relação de composição é representada por um flecha partindo da classe "hospedeira" com um diamante colorado (de preto) até a classe "parte" (sem nenhum símbolo neste extremo, mas no máximo especificando o numero total dessa parte).

Por exemplo, supõe de ter uma classe `Pessoa`, e, como bem sabemos, uma pessoa é "composta" por pernas e braços. Aqui poderias criar uma relação de composição partindo da classe `Pessoa` com uma diamante colorado até a classe `Perna` e `Braço`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota que poderia ter especificado o numero 2 nos extremos `Perna` e `Braço`, porque felizmente a maior parte das pessoas têm 2 braços e pernas.

No teu primeiro caso especifico, na segunda flecha o diamante deveria estar da parte da classe `C`, visto que tu queres `C` como o todo (ou a classe "hospedeira").

Em general, tu podes ter as combinações de relações que tu bem entendes. Claramente algumas têm mais sentido do que outras. Mesmo assim o teu segundo diagrama não representa aquilo que tu gostarias de obter, porque dizes que queres uma "composição" entre `A` e `B`, mas na realidade quando usas um diamante vazio isso quer dizer "agregação". Muito provavelmente trocastes as duas relações.

Existem bons artigos online para perceber mais sobre estás relações:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Composition
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141678/what-does-a-diamond-sign-signify-in-uml-class-diagrams

Entre muitos outros.